# Why when i try to capture a video to mp4 file using directshow the file is empty?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directshow

And when I quit the program the mp4 file deleted automatic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DirectShowLib;
using DirectShowLib.BDA;
using DirectShowLib.DES;
using DirectShowLib.DMO;
using DirectShowLib.Dvd;
using DirectShowLib.MultimediaStreaming;
using DirectShowLib.SBE;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Management;
using System.IO;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace Youtube_Manager
{

    public partial class Elgato_Video_Capture : Form
    {
        IFileSinkFilter sink;

        IFilterGraph2 graph;
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph;
        Size videoSize;
        string error = "";
        List<Object> devices = new List<Object>();
        IMediaControl mediaControl;

        public Elgato_Video_Capture()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (comboBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                for (int xx = 1; xx <= 8; xx++)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(xx);
                }
            }

            InitDevice();

        }

        IPin outPin;
        IPin inPin;
        private void InitDevice()
        {
            try
            {
                //Set the video size to use for capture and recording
                videoSize = new Size(827, 505);//1280, 720);

                //Initialize filter graph and capture graph
                graph = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
                captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
                captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(graph);
                //Create filter for Elgato
                Guid elgatoGuid = new Guid("39F50F4C-99E1-464A-B6F9-D605B4FB5918");
                Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(elgatoGuid);
                IBaseFilter  elgatoFilter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
                graph.AddFilter(elgatoFilter, "Elgato Video Capture Filter");

                //Create smart tee filter, add to graph, connect Elgato's video out to smart tee in
                IBaseFilter smartTeeFilter = (IBaseFilter)new SmartTee();

                graph.AddFilter(smartTeeFilter, "Smart Tee");
                outPin = GetPin(elgatoFilter, "Video");
                inPin = GetPin(smartTeeFilter, "Input");               

                graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

                //Create video renderer filter, add it to graph, connect smartTee Preview pin to video renderer's input pin
                IBaseFilter videoRendererFilter = (IBaseFilter)new VideoRenderer();

                graph.AddFilter(videoRendererFilter, "Video Renderer");
                outPin = GetPin(smartTeeFilter, "Capture");

                inPin = GetPin(videoRendererFilter, "Input");
                graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);

                captureGraph.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Avi, @"e:\screenshots\test1.mp4", out smartTeeFilter, out sink);
                sink.SetFileName(@"e:\screenshots\test1.mp4", null);

                //Render stream from video renderer
                captureGraph.RenderStream(PinCategory.Capture, MediaType.Video, videoRendererFilter, null, null);
                //Set the video preview to be the videoFeed panel
                IVideoWindow vw = (IVideoWindow)graph;
                vw.put_Owner(pictureBox1.Handle);
                vw.put_MessageDrain(this.Handle);
                vw.put_WindowStyle(WindowStyle.Child | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings | WindowStyle.ClipChildren);
                vw.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, 827, 505);

                //Start the preview
                mediaControl = graph as IMediaControl;
                mediaControl.Run();

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                error = err.ToString();
            }
        }

         IPin GetPin(IBaseFilter filter, string pinname)
        {
            IEnumPins epins;
            int hr = filter.EnumPins(out epins);
            checkHR(hr, "Can't enumerate pins");
            IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
            IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];
            while (epins.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
            {
                PinInfo pinfo;
                pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pinfo);
                bool found = (pinfo.name == pinname);
                DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pinfo);
                if (found)
                    return pins[0];
            }
            checkHR(-1, "Pin not found");
            return null;
        }

        public  void checkHR(int hr, string msg)
        {
            if (hr < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
                DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }            
        }
}
```

I added this part now to my code:

```
captureGraph.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Avi, @"e:\screenshots\test1.mp4", out smartTeeFilter, out sink);
sink.SetFileName(@"e:\screenshots\test1.mp4", null);
```

I see the preview but the mp4 file is empty it's not saving the video to the file at all.
What I wanted to do is to save the video stream using the directshow to a mp4 file.
Now all I can get is to see a preview of the video in a pictureBox.

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't capture to a MP4-File, you capture to an AVI-File with just an MP4-extension! DirectShow has no native MP4-Mux. You need to install one seperatly like the [GDCL MP4 Mux](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/).
2. I don't think your connections are working correctly. With DirectShowNet you need to check the return codes and then throw the exceptions yourself, like:

   ```
   int hr = graph.Connect(outPin, inPin);;
   DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
   ```
3. Your `captureGraph.RenderStream` is useless because a VideoRender-Filter has no output-pin. Please look at the [meaning of this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930715.aspx). You can better build this graph with just RenderStream, it is even inserting the SmartTee-Filter for you.

Comment: Ok let's say for now I don't want to use the mp4 mux but save it to avi file even if not compressed. First I want to be able to capture the video right. For the number 2 I see now it throw exception -2147220969 but I don't have a clue what this number meaning. I thought that if I see the preview video then it seems to be working. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: This is the error number: this is your error: 0x80040217: no combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection. that is, vfw_e_cannot_connect. you are trying to connect unconnectable.

Comment: The best is, to build your graph with GraphEdit or [GraphStudioNext](http://www.videohelp.com/software/GraphStudio) before you do it in code. What is the output MediaType of the Elgato-Device?

Comment: Yopu mean in the RenderStream in MediaType.Video ? I see: {73646976-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71}

Comment: That is the GUID for MediaType_Video. No I mean the which MediaSubtype do you get? Is it a uncompressed format or a h.264 stream?